# How to Disable SolrAutoConfiguration.class in Grails 3.0.2

Tags: grails

Among other changes, **SolrServer** has been renamed in **SolrClient** in solr **5.x**.

Grails applications that depends on solr 5.x cannot start with Grails 3.0.2 because **SolrAutoConfiguration** tries to create a **SolrServer** instance.

How can I disable "SolrAutoConfiguration"?

I tried to annotate Application class with

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [SolrAutoConfiguration.class])
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
[. . .]
```

but the compiler leaves with a stack overflow...

The error message:

```
ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrServer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/solr/SolrAutoConfiguration.class]: . . .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to annotate Application class with:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [SolrAutoConfiguration])
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration { ...
```

see [Solr 5 with spring boot and grails 3](https://www.tobyhobson.co.uk/solr-5-with-spring-boot-and-grails-3/)