# Actuator health check for SOLR giving Error creating bean with name 'solrClient'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-boot-actuator

I have a simple Spring boot app and want to include Actuator health check for SOLR but seems to be giving error when running it. Anything else that needs to be added a=or configured.

*org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actuatorConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solr'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/solr/SolrAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient]: Factory method 'solrClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient$Builder*

1. SolrHealthIndicator.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.AbstractHealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Health;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.Status;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.CoreAdminRequest;
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.response.CoreAdminResponse;
import org.apache.solr.common.params.CoreAdminParams;


public class SolrHealthIndicator extends AbstractHealthIndicator {

    private final SolrClient solrClient;

    public SolrHealthIndicator(SolrClient solrClient) {
        super("Solr health check failed");
        this.solrClient = solrClient;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doHealthCheck(Health.Builder builder) throws Exception {
         Object status = this.solrClient.ping().getResponse().get("status");
            builder.up().withDetail("solrStatus", status);
//      CoreAdminRequest request = new CoreAdminRequest();
//      request.setAction(CoreAdminParams.CoreAdminAction.STATUS);
//      CoreAdminResponse response = request.process(this.solrClient);
//      int statusCode = response.getStatus();
//      Status status = (statusCode != 0) ? Status.DOWN : Status.UP;
//      builder.status(status).withDetail("status", statusCode);
    }
}
```

2. ActuatorConfiguration.java

```
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.HealthIndicator;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
public class ActuatorConfiguration {

    @Inject
    @Named("solrClient")
    private SolrClient solr;

    @ConditionalOnProperty(value = "solr.health.check.enabled",havingValue = "true")
    @Bean(name = "SearchStorage")
    public HealthIndicator solrHealthIndicator() {
        return new SolrHealthIndicator(solr);
    }
}
```

3)pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
    <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
  <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>
</dependency>
```

4)Complete Stack Trace

```
2020-08-28 23:56:28.113  WARN 83950 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actuatorConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solr'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/solr/SolrAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient]: Factory method 'solrClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient$Builder
2020-08-28 23:56:28.116  INFO 83950 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-08-28 23:56:28.130  INFO 83950 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-28 23:56:28.134 ERROR 83950 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'actuatorConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'solr'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/solr/SolrAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient]: Factory method 'solrClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient$Builder
..

    at com.test.sre.blue.BlueApplication.main(BlueApplication.java:18) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'solrClient' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/solr/SolrAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient]: Factory method 'solrClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient$Builder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:655) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    …..
    ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient]: Factory method 'solrClient' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient$Builder
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:650) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 33 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient$Builder
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.solr.SolrAutoConfiguration.solrClient(SolrAutoConfiguration.java:51) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.3.3.RELEASE.jar:2.3.3.RELEASE]
    ..at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.2.8.RELEASE.jar:5.2.8.RELEASE]
    ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrClient$Builder
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[na:na]
    ... 40 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

You connected spring-boot-autoconfigure
It has org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.solr.SolrAutoConfiguration

and this code is trying to use Solr4.
And you connected Solr5 in pom.xml.

In Solr5, org/apache/solr/client/solrj/impl/HttpSolrClient$Builder was removed.

So solutions:

- disable SolrAutoConfiguration.

I also didn't know this, and found solution on
[How to Disable SolrAutoConfiguration.class in Grails 3.0.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31046466/how-to-disable-solrautoconfiguration-class-in-grails-3-0-2)

```
// Grails 4
@CompileStatic
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.solr.SolrAutoConfiguration.class])
class Application extends GrailsAutoConfiguration {
```

- or update libs